# Firesore Error writing document: Error: 400 undefined: Getting metadata from plugin failed with error

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to write simple data in firestore cloud but these are the errors I'm getting.

this's my code I'm trying to submit data the collection I created

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

var serviceAccount = require("../key4.json");


// var admin = require("firebase-admin");

// var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    // databaseURL: "https://productapi-72b9f-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com"
});


const firestore = admin.firestore();
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const directoryPath = path.join(__dirname, "files");

let data = {
    "itemID": "MOMOS_NV_102",
    "itemName": "Kadi Veg Momos",
    "itemPriceHalf": 80,
    "itemPriceFull": 130,
    "hasImage": false,
    "itemCategory": "momos_nv",
    "itemType": "nv"
}

const items = firestore.collection('items').doc('BJ');
const res = items.set(data).then(() => {
        console.log("Document successfully written!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
    });
```

```
{
  code: '400',
  details: 'Getting metadata from plugin failed with error: invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim.',
  metadata: Metadata { internalRepr: Map {}, options: {} },
  note: 'Exception occurred in retry method that was not classified as transient'
}
```

is this something related TOKEN? how I can solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution as synchronizing the windows 10 date/time